# stack corruption detected when use memset in c++ from JNI Android

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, memset

I am developing an Android application using C++ native code.

I have C++ code (XTTEA Algorithm in C++ native) which perfectly runs online with C++ compiler and I can get the output, but when I try to use that class method using JNI cpp class, it give me the error below:

```
A/libc: stack corruption detected (-fstack-protector)
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 13328 (example.ndkdemo), pid 13328 (example.ndkdemo)
```

Below is the JNI cpp code where I pass the data as input.

```cpp
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALLJava_com_example_ndkdemo_MainActivity_encryptDataInt(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz /* this */){
//    return add(5,3);

    int len;

    unsigned char input[8] = { 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11, 0x11 };

    sg_xxtea_encrypt (input, 8);

    return 1;
}
```

Below is the method that I call from above JNI code. I debug the code and find out that the error occurs in the `memset()` function inside the first `if` conditon.

```cpp
int
sg_xxtea_encrypt (unsigned char *data, int data_size)
{
    int i = 0;
    int block_size = ((data_size + 2) / 4 + 1) * 4;
    memset (sg_data_buff, 0, ENCRYPT_INT_BUFF * 4);

    if (block_size > data_size)
    {
        memset (&data[data_size], 0, block_size - data_size); // We get error in this line
    }
    for (i = data_size + 1; i >= 2; i--)
    {
        data[i] = data[i - 2];
    }
    data[0] = (data_size >> 8) & 0xff;
    data[1] = (data_size >> 0) & 0xff;
    for (i = 0; i < block_size / 4; i++)
    {
        sg_data_buff[i] = bytesTOint (&data[i * 4]);
    }
    TEA_EncryptCore (block_size, sg_data_buff, sg_key_buff);
    for (i = 0; i < block_size / 4; i++)
    {
        intTobyte (sg_data_buff[i], &data[i * 4]);
    }
    return block_size;
}
```

Can anyone please suggest what could be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `input` array is 8 bytes.  The `data` parameter is a pointer to `input`, and the `data_size` parameter is 8, so  the`block_size` variable is calculated as 12. Your `memset()` is writing 4 `0x00` bytes to `&data[data_size]`, aka `&input[8]`, which is out of bounds of the `input` array. So, you have a buffer overflow that is corrupting stack memory surrounding the `input` array.

The subsequent `for` loop after the `memset()` is also accessing the `input` array's elements out of bounds, too.

`input` is a fixed sized array. Accessing elements outside of its bounds does not make it grow larger.

Comment: Remy, 

When we run the c++ code in the online c++ compiler then we are not getting the stack error or we can say index error.

Can you please suggest what modification i need to do to fix the stack error. 

When I try below line with 12 then still it crash.

sg_xxtea_encrypt (input, 12);

Comment: @bluepixeltechnologies `input` is still 8 bytes even if you set `data_size` to 12, then `block_size` is 16, and corruption still occurs. Stack corruption is **undefined behavior**. Different compilers will react to UB in different ways. But make no mistake, your code IS corrupting memory, in ANY compiler. The side effects are unpredictable, and the lack of any errors is not an indication of good code. You need to fix your code's logic, as it is accessing memory it is not allowed to access. `input` needs to be allocated at least as large as `block_size`, even if `data_size` is smaller.

Comment: Thank you it is very helpful we solved the bug by modifying our code